# Separating SQL Tables while still allowing connections

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table with 6 columns, Continent,Country,City,lat,long and id, however i need to separate these into 3 different tables, one for continents, one for countries and one for cities and the location data but they still needed to be connected through foreign keys. for example instead of  Australia ,Australia Melbourne, it would be Australia_id, Australia_id, Melbourne. Is this possible to do with an SQL query without losing all the data i have in my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MainTable` should have

```
 id , city_id, lat, long
```

Then you have 3 table `continent`, `country` and `city` with

```
 continent_id, continent_name
 continent_id, country_id, country_name
 country_id, city_id, city_name
```

Then you query is.

```
 SELECT M.*, CI.city_name, CO.country_name, CN.continent_name
 FROM MainTable M
 JOIN city CI
   ON M.city_id = CI.city_id
 JOIN country CO 
   ON CI.country_id = CO.country_id
 JOIN continent CN
   ON CO.continent_id = CN.continent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the basis of how a relational database works.

You would have a continent_id though.

```
Country_id, Continent_id, City
```

Depending on your application though it may not be that useful to split them up. That information is fairly static, and joining every time you want it would be annoying, regardless of how trivial it is.

Comment: The splitting of them was a request made to reduce the number of duplicate entries in which errors coiuldoccur, so i dont really have a choice in this matter